# How to change Python background to a certain colour with colorama?

Tags: python-3.x, colorama

I am using colorama to change the colour of my text and it works fines, but now I want to change the colour of the whole background instead of just my text.

I am using Windows:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

colorama.init()

print(Back.GREEN)
print(Fore.RED)
```

But, that code only makes the text coloured. Is there a way to do that in python? I want it like CMD where you can have the background of it a colour. I cannot use the OS module as I do not have admin rights, but I'm open to using any other module.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while in playing with it i figured it out. Just forgot about this post. Here is what I did.

```
import colorama
from colorama import Back as bg

colorama.init()
print(bg.RED)
print(colorama.ansi.clear_screen())
```

I think clearing the screen fixed the Issue

Answer (score 2):

After playing with colorama on my Windows 10 box it seems it's only used to change the text but not the console/terminal background. I was however able to change the background using this standard library solution:

```
import ctypes

try:
    ctypes.windll.msvcrt.system(b"color 4f")
    print("Hello World!")
except ValueError:
    pass
```

The terminal background will change to red with white text.

Comment: Just as a note, I think `os.system(...)` should do the same.